# rosrun cannot find executables

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realize this question has been asked to death, but when running `rosrun raspicam raspicam_node` I get the message `[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named raspicam_node below /opt/ros/indigo/share/raspicam`.

I am running Raspbian jessie on a Raspberry Pi 2 with ROS Indigo. catkin_make_isolated was used to build the workspace.
I placed the following lines in .bashrc:

`source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks export ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws`

Prior to running `rosrun`, I enter the ros_catkin_ws directory and input `source devel_isolated/setup.bash`
The executable exists under `ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/raspicam/lib/raspicam`.
If I move the executable to `ros_catkin_ws/src/raspicam/src`, everything works fine, but I would rather it work without manually moving files.

Output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`

Before sourcing: `/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks`

after sourcing: `/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/image_transport_plugins/theora_image_transport:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231767/rosrun-cannot-find-executables./) by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2016-04-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2016-04-12**:
You can try `source devel_isolated/setup.bash --extend` instead. Without the extend flag, the last sourced file overwrites all of the previously loaded ones.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2016-04-12**:
If that does not help, please, edit your question and append the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` after you source your workspace. And another thing - is the executable a Python script? If so, they have custom handling that allows you to run files directly from the source space.

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2016-04-12**:
I added the output of echo `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` before and after sourcing. This is clearly a problem.
The script is c++ not Python.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2016-04-13**:
I think the `.bashrc` lines are not correct. Try `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash; source /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash --extend;` and do NOT manually set `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` nor `ROS_WORKSPACE`. And also make sure you've built your workspace with `catkin_make` and try in a new terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem seems to have been fixed by putting the raspicam package in a separate workspace.

---

Originally posted by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) with karma: 107 on 2016-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-25**:
Haha , mahnnnn. Thanks for this .

Changing the workspace somehow fixed the problem .

Was breaking my head over it for over 2-3hours!